# How can I filter out or remove achievement screenshots?

Tags: ps4

PS4 takes a screenshot for every achievement I get. Because of that my Capture Gallery is cluttered with these useless screenshots (some of them are memorable black screens).

How can I see only screenshots that I took? Is it possible to filter our or drop all achievement screenshots?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's sadly no way to only see screenshots that you've made manually. However, to stop the PS4 from taking this many screenshots:

1. Press the Share button

When the Share screen appears, push the options button to bring up a side menu down the right of the screen. Scroll down to 'Share Settings' and select it.

2. Enter the Share Settings menu
3. Enter the Screenshot Settings menu
4. Disable automatic Trophy screenshots

Once you're in the Screenshot Settings menu, you should find an option labeled 'Take Automatically When You Earn Trophy'. Disable that.

Comment: This feature should just be off by default IMO. I'd imagine for most people it's just clutter (if they even check their gallery at all). Like OP, a good majority were just plain black screens anyway. Or at the very least just crummy pictures altogether...

Comment: @BrootsWaymb definitely not. I love to have a screenshot next to my trophies, and one may discover this feature only after months. Since you can always disable it and delete what you feel as useless, it's an easy fix as it is.